# Kivy AnchorPoint is not in the right place

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to just put a piece of text centred in the top on the window but it ends up truncated in the bottom left.

I have the following python code:

```
# anchortest.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Root(Widget):
    pass

class TextTitle(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class AnchorTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

AnchorTestApp().run()
```

and it's associated `kv` file.

```
# anchortest.kv

<Root>
    TextTitle:

<TextTitle>
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'

    Label:
        id: score
        text: 'Hello World'
        font_name: 'Courier New'
        font_size: 40
        pad_x: 10
        pad_y: 10
```

When I run the app I get this:

[image: Window UI with the "hello world" text in the bottom left, only half is showing.]

Comment: Try inheriting your `Root` class from a layout class like `BoxLayout`, `FloatLayout` etc.

Comment: I set it to box layout and now the text is centred in the screen. Slowly getting there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `AnchorLayout` for this case, just use `BoxLayout` with

```py
pos_hint: {'top': 1}
size_hint_y: None
```

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

KV = """   
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        BoxLayout:
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            size_hint_y: None
            
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: [0.5, 0, 1, 1]
                    
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
            Label:
                text: 'Hello World'
                font_size: sp(60)
                
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Screen text'
"""


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


TestApp().run()
```

You also can use `Label` parametrs `valign` and `halign`:

```py
KV = """   
Screen:
    Label:
        text: 'Hello World'
        font_size: sp(60)
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'top'
"""
```

> In order to control sizing, you must specify `text_size` to constrain
> the text and/or bind size to `texture_size` to grow with the text.

If you really want to use `AnchorLayout` for some reason, it's done this way. Following the [kivy](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/) documentation, in order for the `AnchorLayout` rules to apply, the `Label` must be set with

```
size_hint_y: None
height: self.height
```

> The size_hint is a tuple of values used by layouts to manage the sizes
> of their children. It indicates the size relative to the layout’s size
> instead of an absolute size (in pixels/points/cm/etc)

```py
KV = """ 
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'
            
    Label:
        text: 'Hello World'
        font_size: sp(60)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.height
"""
```